# StaleElementReference error in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am working on a web scraper that scrapes top 50 FPL managers, and finds which players are on their team. I have a working code that uses time.sleep() that is working, but is very slow:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver.exe')
wait = 1.5

gk_list, def_list, mid_list, attack_list, subst_list = [],[],[],[],[]

driver.get('https://fantasy.premierleague.com/leagues/314/standings/c')

sleep(wait)

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[5]/button[1]').click() #Accepts cookies

for i in range(1,51): #Loop with common XPATH numbers for top 50 FPL players
    navn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'/html/body/main/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[{i}]/td[2]/a/strong')
    sleep(wait)
    navn.click() #Clicks on the user
    sleep(wait)
    
    #Trying to find the goalkeeper
    gk_list.append(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/main/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/button/div/div[1]').text)
    for k in range(1,6):
        try: #Trying to find the defenders
            def_list.append(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'/html/body/main/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[{k}]/div/div/button/div/div[1]').text)
        except NoSuchElementException: #Skips elements that does not exist
            pass

        try: #Trying to find the midfielders
            mid_list.append(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'/html/body/main/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[{k}]/div/div/button/div/div[1]').text)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            pass

        try: #Trying to find the attackers
            attack_list.append(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'/html/body/main/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[4]/div[{k}]/div/div/button/div/div[1]').text)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            pass

        try: #Trying to find the subs
            subst_list.append(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, f'/html/body/main/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[{k}]/div/div/button/div/div[1]').text)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            pass

    sleep(wait)
    driver.back() #Returns to main page


driver.quit()


gk_dict = dict() #Converts list to dictionary, key is player, value is player occurrence
for i in gk_list:
    gk_dict[i] = gk_dict.get(i,0) + 1

def_dict = dict() 
for i in def_list:
    def_dict[i] = def_dict.get(i,0) + 1

mid_dict = dict() 
for i in mid_list:
    mid_dict[i] = mid_dict.get(i,0) + 1

attack_dict = dict() 
for i in attack_list:
    attack_dict[i] = attack_dict.get(i,0) + 1

subst_dict = dict() 
for i in subst_list:
    subst_dict[i] = subst_dict.get(i,0) + 1

gk_sorted = {k: v for k, v in sorted(gk_dict.items(), key = lambda v: v[1], reverse=True)} #Sorts the dictionaries from high values to low
def_sorted = {k: v for k, v in sorted(def_dict.items(), key = lambda v: v[1], reverse=True)}
mid_sorted = {k: v for k, v in sorted(mid_dict.items(), key = lambda v: v[1], reverse=True)}
attack_sorted = {k: v for k, v in sorted(attack_dict.items(), key = lambda v: v[1], reverse=True)}
subst_sorted = {k: v for k, v in sorted(subst_dict.items(), key = lambda v: v[1], reverse=True)}

print("\nKeepers:\n", gk_sorted,"\n")
print("\nDefenders:\n", def_sorted,"\n")
print("\nMidfielders:\n", mid_sorted,"\n")
print("\nAttackers:\n", attack_sorted,"\n")
print("\nSubs:\n", subst_sorted,"\n")
```

I also got sent a code with explicit wait instead of time.sleep(), that should be much faster. However, it returns "StaleElementReference:Element is not attached to the page" error in the "each_one" loop. I have no idea how to fix it, i would appreciate some help.
Code with explicit wait:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver.exe')

gk_list, def_list, mid_list, attack_list, subst_list = [], [], [], [], []

driver.get('https://fantasy.premierleague.com/leagues/314/standings/c')

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[5]/button[1]'))).click()  # Accepts cookies

# Loop with common XPATH numbers for top 50 FPL players
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'table')))
top_50 = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//table//tbody//tr//td//following-sibling::td/a")
for each_one in top_50:
    print(each_one.text)
    each_one.click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[text()='List View']"))).click()
    players = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//th[text()='Starters']//ancestor::table//tr[contains(@class, 'ElementTable__')]")
    for player in players:
        player.click()

        # Trying to find to goalkeeper
        try:
            gkp = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='GKP']//parent::div//preceding-sibling::div")
            for keeper in gkp:
                gk_list.append(keeper.text)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            pass

        try:
            defenders = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='DEF']//parent::div//preceding-sibling::div")
            for defender in defenders:
                def_list.append(defender.text)
        except NoSuchElementException:
            pass
        try:
            attackers = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='MID']//parent::div//preceding-sibling::div")
            for attacker in attackers:
                attack_list.append(attacker.text)

        except NoSuchElementException:
            pass

    try:
        subs = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//th[text()='Substitutes']//ancestor::table//tr[contains(@class, 'ElementTable__')]")
        for each_sub in subs:
            subst_list.append(each_sub.text)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass

    driver.back()  # Returns to main page
    

driver.quit()

gk_dict = dict()  # Converts list to dictionary, key is player, value is player occurrence
for i in gk_list:
    gk_dict[i] = gk_dict.get(i, 0) + 1

def_dict = dict()
for i in def_list:
    def_dict[i] = def_dict.get(i, 0) + 1

mid_dict = dict()
for i in mid_list:
    mid_dict[i] = mid_dict.get(i, 0) + 1

attack_dict = dict()
for i in attack_list:
    attack_dict[i] = attack_dict.get(i, 0) + 1

subst_dict = dict()
for i in subst_list:
    subst_dict[i] = subst_dict.get(i, 0) + 1

gk_sorted = {k: v for k, v in sorted(gk_dict.items(), key=lambda v: v[1],
                                     reverse=True)}  # Sorts the dictionaries from high values to low
def_sorted = {k: v for k, v in sorted(def_dict.items(), key=lambda v: v[1], reverse=True)}
mid_sorted = {k: v for k, v in sorted(mid_dict.items(), key=lambda v: v[1], reverse=True)}
attack_sorted = {k: v for k, v in sorted(attack_dict.items(), key=lambda v: v[1], reverse=True)}
subst_sorted = {k: v for k, v in sorted(subst_dict.items(), key=lambda v: v[1], reverse=True)}

print("\nKeepers:\n", gk_sorted, "\n")
print("\nDefenders:\n", def_sorted, "\n")
print("\nMidfielders:\n", mid_sorted, "\n")
print("\nAttackers:\n", attack_sorted, "\n")
print("\nSubs:\n", subst_sorted, "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try scroll into view
'''

```
def scroll_into_view(self, element):
    try:
        self.driver.execute_script(
            "arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element
        )
        return True
    except BaseException as e:
        raise AssertionError(f"Can't scroll to element into view\n{e}")
```

'''
Or
'''

```
def scroll_to_element(self, element):
    try:
        action = ActionChains(self.driver)
        action.move_to_element(element).perform()
        return True
    except BaseException as e:
        raise AssertionError(f"Can't scroll to element\n{e}")
```

'''

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when would i use the function? Can you paste an example into my script to make it easier for me to understand your answer? @piscoony